# Sending byte array over ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am having ajax request which is working only half way.

```
function receivedText() {
    alert(fr.result); //Here i have good result
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Gallery/UploadImage",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            byteArray: fr.result,
            fileName: $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 0)
                alert("error");
            else
                alert("Success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my request. As you can see i commented up there that in my test(alert) `fr.result` has value BUT when i debug and go see it in my controller, it is NULL.

Here is my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UploadImage(byte[] byteArray, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Uploads\\Images\\" + fileName, byteArray);
        return Json(0);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare `fr`?

Comment: It is byte array.

Comment: I am declaring it in few functions before, but i tested in this one (line i commented) and it has value

Comment: Can you inspect the ajax call and see what's being sent?

Comment: If its a image, why not just try and post it as a base64 string?

Comment: First intention was doing it with base64 but same thing, not working. Right now i am trying to figure out how to inspect ajax call so i will post it here when i find out

Comment: @YaakovAinspan i did inspect it and it sends long string of name `byteArray` and string `fileName`

Comment: At this point, assuming your controller is set up correctly and the function above is getting called, it's probably a decoding issue w/ byteArray. Send the buffer upstream as base64, ensure it's sent correctly, decode with `Convert.FromBase64String(string)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your're using ajax in a wrong way.

1. The first error is **a mismatch with `Content-Type`**

   ```
   $.ajax({
       ...
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       ...
       data: {
           byteArray: fr.result,
           fileName: $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop()
       },
       ...
   }
   ```

   Although you've set the `Content-Type=application/json`, **the payload sent to server will be `form-url-encoded`** by default:

   ```
   fileName=Xyz&byteArray=
   ```

   If you need JSON format, you should use **`JSON.stringify({...})`** to get a text representation.
2. The `contentType: "application/json;` is not suitable here. That's because :

   - The [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Full_JSON_syntax) is not designed to deal with **binary data** but used for **text**. You can't send a `byte[]` with json.
   - The server side code **expects simple type from query/routes/form**. If you need json, they should be something like  `IActionResult UploadImage([FromBody] Fr fr)`
3. If you're sending an image, the easiest way is to use the `Content-Type` of **`multipart/form-data`** with the **`IFormFile`** on the server side at the same time.

   ```
   // action method
   public IActionResult UploadImage(IFormFile image, string fileName)
   {
        // ...
   }
   ```

   and now you could send a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) :

   ```
   // your receivedText() function
   function receivedText(){
       var formData = new FormData();
       formData.append('fileName', 'Xyz.img');

       // if you need upload image
       var inputFileElement=document.getElementById("inputFileImage");
       formData.append('image', inputFileElement.files[0]);

       // of if you're already have a `byte[]`, you could do it as below:
       // var blob = new Blob([bytearray]...); // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob
       // formData.append('image', blob); 

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/Gallery/UploadImage",
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           data: formData,
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               // ...
           },
           error: function () {
               // ...
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

That would be your idea:

```cs
public class UploadImageBindings {
   public string byteArray {get;set;}
   public string fileName {get;set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UploadImage(UploadImageBindings bindings)
{
    try
    {
     var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bindings.byteArray);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Uploads\\Images\\" + bindings.fileName, bytes);
        return Json(0);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json(0);
    }
}
```

Your problem is that you not post as `byte[]` but you have to post as string !